# Crawler state resume

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, pool

### Crawler state resume

In a Python crawler, I need to save the status of finished downloads in an external file on the disk. I'm using a Manager object to create a shared dictionary called shared_fetch_controller. I have N concurrent Pools.starmap workers, each process writes the status of each domain to the shared_fetch_controller dictionary in a simple format:

```
{'03a07eddcc2f56c99bb5c9430a72c9bc': ('https://xxxxxxxxx.com', 1, 1688967337)}
```

where 03a07eddcc2f56c99bb5c9430a72c9bc is the hash of domain

The second field in the tuple starts from 1 and increases when a new URL is found, and decreases when a URL is fetched. When it reaches 0, the domain is considered "fully retrieved" or "complete".

I need to save the state of this dictionary to an external file for resuming the crawler later. I am currently using a separate thread with the following logic:

- Get the shared object.
- Transform it into a normal dictionary.
- Save it to disk.

---

```
try:
    td = dict(shared_fetch_controller)
except Exception as e:
    ppprint(e, 2)
fnt = os.path.join(conf['PATH_DUMPS'], '000_crawl_shared_fetch_controller_tmp.pkl')
fn = os.path.join(conf['PATH_DUMPS'], '000_crawl_shared_fetch_controller.pkl')
with open(fnt, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(td, f)
os.replace(fnt, fn)
```

However, this logic is not working as expected. Initially, with shared_fetch_controller around 300k domains, the serialization operation was hanging because the processes were inserting data into the dictionary while the serialization dict(shared_fetch_controller) was happening. To solve this issue, I introduced a lock as follows:

```
try:
    with lock:
        td = dict(shared_fetch_controller)
except Exception as e:
    ppprint(e, 2)
```

This resolved the hanging issue, but now I am facing problems when the fetch_controller dictionary increases to around one million domains: the serialization process takes between 40 to 60 seconds, during which the workers hangs while waiting for the lock.

Is this time normal?

I temporary solved the problem saving this status every 45 minutes,
my ideas were:

- reducing the shared_fetch_controller to the minimum:
  {'03a07eddcc2f56c99bb5c9430a72c9bc': 0}
- save just the finished (0) domains and not all the states

but both this solutions just postpone the problems to, let's say, 10M or 20M domains.

So, I'd like to ask:

- is there some non-blocking solution to solve this problem?
- is it non sense what's happening, and I make some big mistake that I don't see?

Appreciate any help

Comment: Re, "...dictionary...one million domains..." Maybe it's time to think about using an external database instead of trying to keep everything in a dictionary in memory.